# Get data from JSON getting keyerror 0

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

```
import requests
import simplejson as json
from pprint import pprint

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=london&APPID=3eee8f807f05e481750751ea15da9b80'
response = requests.get(url).json()
pprint(response)
```

when I run this code in my terminal I get

{u'base': u'stations',
 u'clouds': {u'all': 1},
 u'cod': 200,
 u'coord': {u'lat': 29.94, u'lon': -90.35},
 u'dt': 1499812500,
 u'id': 4322034,
 u'main': {u'humidity': 78,
           u'pressure': 1017,
           u'temp': 301.58,
           u'temp_max': 302.15,
           u'temp_min': 300.15},
 u'name': u'London',
 u'sys': {u'country': u'GB',
          u'id': 1184,
          u'message': 0.0037,
          u'sunrise': 1499771353,
          u'sunset': 1499821484,
          u'type': 1},
 u'visibility': 16093,
 u'weather': [{u'description': u'light rain',
               u'icon': u'10d',
               u'id': 500,
               u'main': u'Rain'},
              {u'description': u'thunderstorm',
               u'icon': u'11d',
               u'id': 211,
               u'main': u'Thunderstorm'}],
 u'wind': {u'deg': 191.503, u'speed': 2.17}}

I then run

```
resp_dict = json.loads(response)
```

To create a dictionary out of the json data so that i can get the data from keys but when I run

```
print(resp_dict['weather'])
```

or

```
print(resp_dict['weather'][0])
```

I just get a keyerror 0? Any help would be appreciated!

Also if i run just

```
print resp_dict
```

I also get a keyerror 0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don’t need to use `json.loads` on `response`; `.json()` already did that for you. I’m not sure how that would result in a `KeyError`, but try printing `response['weather']` instead. (Also, use Python 3.)

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is not happening when you attempt to access `weather`, it happens inside the simplejson call of `json.loads`. Because, as Ryan mentioned, the `response` object is already a json (in the format of a dictionary) and the `json.loads` expects a string.

Using the `response` object directly should work

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
print response['weather']
```